# Unstyled list of links inconsistent across github markdown

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I would like an unstyled list of links on github wiki/documentation. My assumption given [adam-p's markdown cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#line-breaks) was that a single press of the `<enter>` key should break the line.

However this:

```
[link1](#link1)
[link2](#link2)
[link3](#link3)
```

Renders as the below on the Github wiki pages:

[image]
[image]
However on the Issues pages it renders differently:

[image]
[image]

I need an unstyled list of links displayed in a block. Why is it not consistent across the Github website? Is this a bug or do i legitimately need to use something like a `<br>` tag?

## Update

Adding 2 spaces to the end of each line works for breaking the line however it also seems to break the links.

[image]

[image]

## Update 2

Through chat with @Chris and further investigating it turns out the broken links issue only appears when editing a page rather than creating one. Exactly the same md renders fine. Therefore we are putting it down to a special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening might be what is shown on [the API documentation for the Markdown rendering service](https://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/#render-an-arbitrary-markdown-document). I've bolded the most important bits:

> The rendering mode. Can be either:
>
> - `markdown` to render a document as plain Markdown, **just like README files are rendered**.
> - `gfm` to render a document as user-content, ***e.g.* like user comments or issues are rendered**. In GFM mode, hard line breaks are always taken into account, and issue and user mentions are linked accordingly.

So, for some reason, GitHub has elected to support two slightly different models depending on where the Markdown code exists.

> I need an unstyled list of links displayed in a block.

Assuming this means you want the behaviour you see in issues, where each link appears on a new line, you can achieve it by following each item with two trailing spaces. This is [how `<br>` tags are represented in the original Markdown implementation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p):

> When you *do* want to insert a `<br />` break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return.

This should work anywhere on GitHub where Markdown is rendered.

Comment: Ok, seems strange to have 2 types, but i can make peace with that. The second part about adding 2 spaces works, but breaks the links. I shall update my question with what I mean.

Comment: @DavidT, that's bizarre. If you replace the two spaces with a literal `<br>`, does the broken link issue remain? (Markdown [very explicitly allows inline HTML](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html)).

Comment: Nope, broken link issue still there. I thought maybe its because of the whitespace. Notice the 2 links that are broken are the only ones with whitespace. So i removed it but still no luck :(

Comment: @DavidT, as a test, what if you leave a blank line in between each link (instead of trailing spaces or `<br>`s)? That should cause each to be put in its own paragraph. It will probably have more whitespace separating each item than you want, but it will be interesting to see what happens.

Comment: I did, and still no luck. Its very strange. I tried with an extra <enter> with and without the whitespace in the name too and still broken. There must be something wrong in the md of `[Application Structure](#applicationstructure)` but i can't see anything.

Comment: Ok so I have narrowed it down. Starting a new wiki page, with `<br>` after each link works fine. However, editing my existing one the links break.

Comment: @DavidT, are the targets (e.g. `#applicationstructure`) valid? They look like links to named anchors or IDs on the same page. If you append that to the URL and hit Enter, does your browser take you to the right place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97538/discussion-between-davidt-and-chris).